# Is there a library for Floating Action Buttons (FAB) with Labels?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, floating-action-button

Is there a library for creating Floating Action Buttons with labels (similar to the Evernote app)?

[Evernote Screenshot](https://lh4.ggpht.com/hIueHCJKvvAUrTrQQSSv6-2zpKMV-fdTIITHhMGfrulky5fEAR6KM1cpyUFD_9_kqw=h900-rw)

The popular libraries seem to be

- https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button (closest to what I want... ability to expand hide "sub" actions)
- https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton (Primary function is to hide/show with a scrollview, recyclerview, or listview)
- https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu (library which has been around pre-lollipop)

Neither of these, to my knowledge, have this capability. Before re-inventing the wheel, has somebody already done this?

Comment: hey, did u get what u wanted? I mean that floating action menu like Evernote. Can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011268/inflating-view-not-working-corrrectly

Comment: None of those libraries have been updated in years. My [ExpandableFab](https://github.com/nambicompany/expandable-fab) library is highly customizable, modern and maintained. Give it a try.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This feature request ended up being implemented in https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button. This includes labels on both the left and right sides.

If you're interested, see the discussion here: https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/issues/22#issuecomment-66155108

<s>Disclaimer: I haven't used this (yet).</s>

**I'd recommend this library over others that I've seen.**

Comment: @Ioeschg please help me , I want to implement a list of options with FAB menu , but there may be many options, so screen height may not be sufficient, is there anyway to make the list of options scrollable

Comment: Better use this variation of the same library for compatibility till API 4.. github.com/str4d/android-floating-action-button

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays there are available techniques of manipulating ***behaviour*** of the view that enable you to program ***FloatinActionButton*** as you want and to have joy that you have made it by yourself!

1. Fade in/out *FloatingActionButton* while scrolling *RecyclerView* . [DETAILS](https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons)
2. Slide down/up , beside it blog says how to:
3. Expand floatingActionButton and show subFloatingButtons. [DETAILS HERE](http://www.sitepoint.com/animating-android-floating-action-button/)

[image]
[image]

There is to much details, "how to do". Therefore I've attached just links to blogs. Anyway I encourage you guys to take a look at those blogs. You will have total control over your application. Currenty I use all solutions from both blog's. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Especially the last library you mentioned looks quite sophisticated. To my knowledge, you can set **any kind of** `View` you want to be shown as a `Button`.

This `View` could simply be a **custom-view** of yours that shows an image as well as a label.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I did give that library a second look. After working with it, it doesn't quite fit the bill for my use case. Unless you have more than 2 items, it looks a little strange laid out radially. Going to keep this open to hopefully draw a few more answers.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking for this functionality: I made an Android library that has this ability and much more, called ExpandableFab (https://github.com/nambicompany/expandable-fab).

The Material Design spec refers to this functionality as ['Speed Dial'](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button#types-of-transitions) and ExpandableFab implements it along with many additional features.

Nearly everything is customizable (colors, text, size, placement, margins, animations and more) and optional (don't need an Overlay, or FabOptions, or Labels, or icons, etc). Every property can be accessed or set through XML layouts or programmatically - whatever you prefer.

Written 100% in Kotlin but comes with full JavaDoc and KDoc (published API is well documented). Also comes with an example app so you can see different use cases with 0 coding.

Github: https://github.com/nambicompany/expandable-fab

Library website (w/ links to full documentation): https://nambicompany.github.io/expandable-fab/

[image: Regular ExpandableFab implementing Material Design 'Speed Dial' functionality]
[image: A highly customized ExpandableFab implementing Material Design 'Speed Dial' functionality]