# android: floatingaction button for API 19

Tags: android, button, material-design, floating

I am looking for the implementation of floatingaction button for API 19.
I am still using ADT . Is there any library that i can directly use in project.
I saw some libraries in AndroidSTudio but didnt succeed in porting to eclipse.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/samples/FloatingActionButtonBasic/index.html here this link will have sample project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a library for Floating Action Buttons (FAB) with Labels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740107/is-there-a-library-for-floating-action-buttons-fab-with-labels)

Comment: i saw android studio libraries. I am looking for one thats using ADT / eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Here is [my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098626/1891118) describing a library with `FloatingActionButton` implementation.

You may use it even for **API level 7**! It also supports the `elevation` feature from API 21.