# Android: Vertically expanded Floating Action Button

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button

Is there a way to achieve a feature like this https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/raw/master/screenshots/menu.gif in android app using material design support library. I don't wanna use any third party library to achieve this feature.

Comment: Look at my post, where you find solutions easy to reach by yourself http://stackoverflow.com/a/36779809/2163045

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40647621/4961126

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Design Support Library Fab menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699302/android-design-support-library-fab-menu)

Answer (score 19):

Currently, the only way to do it **quickly and easily** is by using third-party libraries.

Yes, it can be done using the Floating Button provided in the design library and it will be a whole lot of work.

I have been using the mentioned library for long and didn't have any problem at all. In my opinion, better to use a third-party library and get started quickly and focus on the core app logic more.

If you want I can give you links to more libraries.

Hope it helps you.

**UPDATE**

1) Rapid Floating Button ([link](https://github.com/wangjiegulu/RapidFloatingActionButton))

2) Floating Action Button ([link](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton))

3) Floating Action Button ([link](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton))

4) Android Floating Action Button ([link](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)) - This is the one I am using. I needed to modify and add few of my own methods to support my apps demands.

Thanks.

Comment: @Priya Did the answer and the links provided help you?

Comment: @Priya That's great! Do let me know if you need any customization help on it. If your problem is solved, then please accept the answer or upvote.

Comment: @Priya Please accept the answer if you got some help from it. Its the way of saying "thank you" in SO.

Comment: How to import this project into eclipse?

Answer (score 8):

It can be achieved by defining multiple FABs in your layout with all but one (the root FAB) initially hidden. Then add logic to display the hidden FABs when the root fab is clicked. To give users that warm fuzzy feeling add some animations into the mix. Its not as complicated as the accepted answer seems to suggest.

This is [a good tutorial on how to do it](https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-floating-action-button-animations.html).

Comment: I find this the best answer as the OP stated that they didn't want to use third party libraries.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest and easiest way to achieve this is using `animate().translationY(int x)` function, you can animate the Floating Action button vertically using the function `animate().translationY(int x)`

In case you are looking for the code in kotlin you can see the code in my github repo [animating-FAB](https://github.com/ajay-dewari/Animating-FAB)

Before writing the code, setup your xml in a way the Floating action button should overlap each other so only one FAB should be vissable:
`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now jumping to the `MainActivity.java` code you can sinply make two functions, to expend the FAB and collapse the FAB as shown below:

```
 private void expendFABMenu(){
    fab1.animate().translationY(- 
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.standard_55));
    fab2.animate().translationY(- 
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.standard_105));
    fab3.animate().translationY(- 
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.standard_155));
}

private void collapseFABMenu(){
    isFABOpen=false;
    fab1.animate().translationY(0);
    fab2.animate().translationY(0);
    fab3.animate().translationY(0);
}
```

Now just add the click listener on the FAB from which you want to expend and collapse the FABs.

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(isFABExpened) {
            isFABExpened = false;
            collapseFABMenu();
        } else {
            isFABExpened = true;
            expendFABMenu();
        }
    }
});
```

Isn't that was simple, you can check the complete java code in my [github repository](https://github.com/ajay-dewari/FloatingActionButton-Menu). In case you are looking for code in kotlin you can check my other github repo [animating-FAB](https://github.com/ajay-dewari/Animating-FAB).

[image]

Comment: Great answer - just missing the following otherwise the fabs jumps to the start of the constraints "android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"